# socket.io linking local jQuery gives 404

Tags: jquery, node.js, socket.io

I want to use a local version of jQuery on my socket.io app which runs on port 8000

when I try to link it I get 404. I tried all the below:

```
<script src=" js/vendor/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<script src=" http://localhost/js/vendor/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<script src=" http://localhost:8000/js/vendor/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
```

I don't want to use google CDN. How do I link it?

Comment: I think that you forgot to handle static files. Are you using any HTTP server framework (e.g. Express)?

Comment: You should learn basic expressjs tutorial for this .. it's not related to socket.io ;)

Comment: `app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));` store your jquery in your public/js folder and use `<script src="js/jquery.js></script>"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should look something like

```
var express = require('express'),
    http = require('http');

var app = express();

app.configure ( function () {
    app.use('/js', express.static(__dirname + '/js'));
});

var server = http.createServer(app).listen(8000);

var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);  // Your app passed to socket.io

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) { console.log('socket connected') });
```

And place your jquery file in your app/js/vendor directory ;)